# Android edge detection opencv

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am creating a project, where I have to remove the background from the image and detect the object.

I am using canny edge detection for detecting edges and than finding contours and than draw contours on a masked image, but after canny edge detection, I am getting broken edges ,how to fix that.

For Canny edge detection, for Threshold parameter, I have tried using thresholding with otsu's method for higher and lower threshold, but it doesn't seem to give appropriate result. Further, I have tried finding the mean of pixel values, and finding

```
double high_threshold = 1.33 * d;
double low_threshold = 0.66 * d;
```

it is also not giving accurate result. what else I can do

```
Mat rgba = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, rgba);
Mat edges = new Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, edges, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(edges, edges, new Size(3,3), 2); Mat thresh=new Mat();
double upper_threshold = Imgproc.threshold(edges,thresh,0,255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C| Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
double lower_threshold = 0.1*upper_threshold;Imgproc.Canny(edges,edges,upper_threshold,lower_threshold,3,false);Mat mDilatedMat = new Mat();

Mat Meroded = new Mat();
double erosion_size=5;
double dilation_size=4;
Mat e=  Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new  Size(2*erosion_size + 1, 2*erosion_size+1));
Mat f=  Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new  Size(2*dilation_size + 1, 2*dilation_size+1));
Imgproc.dilate(edges, mDilatedMat,e);
Imgproc.erode(mDilatedMat, Meroded,f);
```

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191762/i-want-to-detect-objects-in-the-image-and-redraw-it-in-another-page-so-anyone-w) helps

Comment: actually i  m having issue in edge detection,and basically i have to detect edges of random images,so shape won't be a solution.   actually i am converting the image into grayscale and there is issue of intensity maybe..

Comment: Have you tried other edge detectors? Like LoG

Comment: @AmitayNachmani is it  a good option to divide a larger image into blocks of 9 or 12 and then perform edge detection on each block

Comment: I think not. You will get discontinuities between the blocks and inside the blocks there will not be any change in the edges.

Comment: Another suggestion that i have is to try increasing the contrast og the image using histogram equalization.

Comment: can you please share some links regarding that @AmitayNachmani

Comment: tried histogram equilization,a little better result ,but not perfect.what else could be done?

Comment: Can please you post the image so i can look with what you are dealing with

Comment: heeyy!!  i want to know how to get the median  from the histogram of an image .

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your image extracted by sobel , canny or a different algorithm by applying edge linking algorithm.
Many edge linking algorithms are avaliable to use such as hough transform,
ant colony algorithm etc.

Comment: hey,thanks for the response.I just getting the problem at that stage where the intensity of forground and background is almost same in grayscale image ,hence the canny method doesn't detect it any edge.how to fix that up. @FreeMan